# Punishment for apostasy in Catholicism

Tags: catholicism, apostasy

Is there a punishment for apostasy (leaving Christian faith all together) according to the Catholic faith ? If yes, what's the punishment ?

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/47191/1787).

Comment: The linked question is about joining a Protestant group. This question, however, is about apostasy (i.e., leaving the Church an becoming a non-Christian), which is not exactly the same thing. Do you think that is different enough? It is true that the penalty is essentially the same.

Comment: @SpiderRico Is your question answered by the linked question? If not, can you please [edit] this to clarify exactly what kind of apostasy you're talking about, and then we can reopen this question.

Comment: Did so. I agree with Athanasius's comment.